# Problems with boost library and c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am trying to learn how boost filesystem work, but I can't get through some compilation problems

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
  path p = current_path();
  directory_iterator it{p};
  while (it != directory_iterator{})
    std::cout << *it++ << '\n';
}
```

this is how I try to compile.
My g++ version is 4.7

```
g++ -std=c++11 filesystem.cc -lboost_filesystem  -o filesystem
```

After this I get thousands of errors.
For example

```
  In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/interoperable.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_basic_impl<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::value’:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:295:5:   required from ‘const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_impl<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::value’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:418:1:   required from ‘struct boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/nested_type_wknd.hpp:26:31:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::aux::nested_type_wknd<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/or.hpp:48:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/detail/enable_if.hpp:68:12:   required from ‘struct boost::iterators::enable_if<boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >, bool>’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:67:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, bool>’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:837:3:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Derived1, class V1, class TC1, class Reference1, class Difference1, class Derived2, class V2, class TC2, class Reference2, class Difference2> typename boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type boost::operator!=(const boost::iterator_facade<Derived1, V1, TC1, Reference1, Difference1>&, const boost::iterator_facade<Derived2, V2, TC2, Reference2, Difference2>&) [with Derived1 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >; V1 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >; TC1 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference1 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&; Difference1 = long int; Derived2 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >; V2 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >; TC2 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference2 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&; Difference2 = long int]’
filesystem.cc:10:35:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:136:49: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::basic_directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16:0,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:891:11: note: ‘boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::basic_directory_iterator(const boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:891:11: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:168:25: note: ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/interoperable.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:128:41: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘static boost::type_traits::yes_type boost::detail::checker<T>::_m_check(T, int) [with T = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >; boost::type_traits::yes_type = char]’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::throw_exception(const E&) [with E = boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >]’:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:280:9:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<Path>, boost::filesystem::file_status>::type boost::filesystem::symlink_status(const Path&) [with Path = boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits>; typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<Path>, boost::filesystem::file_status>::type = boost::filesystem::file_status]’
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:287:45:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:65:56: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >::clone_impl(const boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:377:9: note: ‘boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >::clone_impl(const boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:377:9: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::error_info_injector(const boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >&)’
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:287:9: note: ‘boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >::error_info_injector(const boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:287:9: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::basic_filesystem_error(const boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:681:11: note: ‘boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::basic_filesystem_error(const boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:681:11: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_imp>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_imp>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:168:25: note: ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_imp>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_imp>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char>, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >::m_imp>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void boost::throw_exception(const E&) [with E = boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >]’:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:261:9:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<Path>, boost::filesystem::file_status>::type boost::filesystem::status(const Path&) [with Path = boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits>; typename boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<Path>, boost::filesystem::file_status>::type = boost::filesystem::file_status]’
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:620:34:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:65:56: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > > >::clone_impl(const boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > > >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/throw_exception.hpp:37:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:377:9: note: ‘boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > > >::clone_impl(const boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:377:9: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >::error_info_injector(const boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >&)’
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:287:9: note: ‘boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >::error_info_injector(const boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/exception/exception.hpp:287:9: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::basic_filesystem_error(const boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:681:11: note: ‘boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::basic_filesystem_error(const boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:681:11: error: use of deleted function ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::m_imp>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::m_imp>&)’
In file included from /usr/include/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:168:25: note: ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::m_imp>::shared_ptr(const boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::m_imp>&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘boost::shared_ptr<boost::filesystem::basic_filesystem_error<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >::m_imp>’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
In file included from /usr/include/boost/iterator/interoperable.hpp:13:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/boost/filesystem.hpp:16,
                 from filesystem.cc:1:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_basic_impl<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >&, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >::value’:
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:295:5:   required from ‘const bool boost::detail::is_convertible_impl<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >::value’
/usr/include/boost/type_traits/is_convertible.hpp:418:1:   required from ‘struct boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/nested_type_wknd.hpp:26:31:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::aux::nested_type_wknd<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > > >’
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/or.hpp:48:8:   required from ‘struct boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/detail/enable_if.hpp:68:12:   required from ‘struct boost::iterators::enable_if<boost::mpl::or_<boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >, boost::is_convertible<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> > >, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >, bool>’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:67:12:   required from ‘struct boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >, bool>’
/usr/include/boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp:837:3:   required by substitution of ‘template<class Derived1, class V1, class TC1, class Reference1, class Difference1, class Derived2, class V2, class TC2, class Reference2, class Difference2> typename boost::detail::enable_if_interoperable<Derived1, Derived2, typename boost::mpl::apply2<boost::detail::always_bool2, Derived1, Derived2>::type>::type boost::operator!=(const boost::iterator_facade<Derived1, V1, TC1, Reference1, Difference1>&, const boost::iterator_facade<Derived2, V2, TC2, Reference2, 
Difference2>&) [with Derived1 =
```

further part

```
boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >; V1 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >; TC1 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference1 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >&; Difference1 = long int; Derived2 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >; V2 = boost::filesystem::basic_directory_entry<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<wchar_t>, boost::filesystem::wpath_traits> >; TC2 = boost::single_pass_traversal_tag; Reference2 =
```

Comment: *"After this I get thousands of errors. For example (...)"*, usually, only the first one matters, and the one you pasted says nothing

Comment: You've omitted the actual error message.

Comment: Always start at the first (top) error message. Many errors in C++ can give follow-up errors that aren't really actual errors. If you fix the first error, many others might go away.

Comment: You need `-lboost_system` before `lboost_filesystem` I think when compiling.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 
I added nearly all errors I have. I resolved the problem by changing {} brackets to () and getting rid of -std=c++11. Somehow than it is working.

Comment: Just a guess, but is it possible that your boost has been compiled without c++11 support? Did you build it by your own?

Comment: GCC 4.7 is pretty old by now, and has very incomplete support for C++11. Even updating to 4.8 (still old and with incomplete C++11 support) would be better if you could, and later versions would be even better of course.